# Add item decoration to recycler view from the end of the adapter

Tags: android

I'm using a `DividerItemDecoration` on a `GridLayout`. It works fine for both direction, but it adds the divider at the bottom of the last row items, and I don't want that. I see that `RecyclerView.addItemDecoration` has this parameter :

```
@param index Position in the decoration chain to insert this decoration at. If this value is negative the decoration will be added at the end.
```

So I try to pass `-3` thinking the decorations would be added from bottom to top skipping the 2 last items of the adapter. But it didn't.

I can I achieve this without creating a duplicate of `DividerItemDecoration` to simply change the loop iteration in `drawVertical` ?

Answer (score 1):

Create a new class

```
private class NoBottomDividerItemDecoration extends DividerItemDecoration {

    public NoBottomDividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
        super(context, orientation);
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        super.getItemOffsets(outRect, view, parent, state);
        if (parent.getChildAdapterPosition(view) == parent.getAdapter().getItemCount() - 1) {
            outRect.set(0, 0, 0, 0);
        }        
    }
}
```

Use this class instead of `DividerItemDecoration`. This will remove the last divider.

Comment: okay so I can override the `getItemOffsets` to not draw the last dividers. But I was asking if it is possible to do it through the `index` parameter without extending/overriding anything. Still, that's better than what I had, thanks